# return true if all objects in array has value in property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, something like this:

```
$scope.objectArray = [
  {Title: 'object1', Description: 'lorem', Value: 57},
  {Title: 'object2', Description: 'ipsum', Value: 32},
  {Title: 'object3', Description: 'dolor', Value: 135}
]
```

I would like to check, and return true, if all objects in this array has an value inside the property 'value'.

I think I could do it with an forEach loop, but is there a better way than this?

```
var isTrue = true;
angular.forEach(objectArray, function(o){
  if (!o.Value){
    isTrue = false; // change variable 'isTrue' to false if no value
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you need it? In HTML? You can use ng-repeat and a filter

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, I belive it could be, in rare cases though, I saw your solution, testing it as I type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), if `0` does not count.

```js
var $scope = { objectArray: [{ Title: 'object1', Description: 'lorem', Value: 57 }, { Title: 'object2', Description: 'ipsum', Value: 32 }, { Title: 'object3', Description: 'dolor', Value: 135 }] },
    isTrue = $scope.objectArray.every(function (a) {
        return a.Value;
    });

document.write(isTrue);
```

Solution with test for `0` as a value.

```js
var $scope = { objectArray: [{ Title: 'object1', Description: 'lorem', Value: 0 }, { Title: 'object2', Description: 'ipsum', Value: 32 }, { Title: 'object3', Description: 'dolor', Value: 135 }] },
    isTrue = $scope.objectArray.every(function (a) {
        return a.Value || a.Value === 0;
    });

document.write(isTrue);
```

Comment: Will be going with this solution, handles the edge case of 0 as value, and was able to edit it a little for another use

Comment: @klskl Please mention in the question that you want to allow `0` value too.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var isTrue = objectArray.every(obj => obj.Value);
```

```js
var objectArray = [
  {Title: 'object1', Description: 'lorem', Value: 57},
  {Title: 'object2', Description: 'ipsum', Value: 32},
  {Title: 'object3', Description: 'dolor', Value: 135}
];

var isTrue = objectArray.every(obj => obj.Value);
document.body.innerHTML = isTrue;
```

---

**Update:**

To handle `0` value, [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) can be used.

```
objectArray.every(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Value'))
```

```js
var objectArray = [
  {Title: 'object1', Description: 'lorem', Value: 57},
  {Title: 'object2', Description: 'ipsum', Value: 32},
  {Title: 'object3', Description: 'dolor', Value: 0}
];

var isTrue = objectArray.every(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Value'));
document.body.innerHTML = isTrue;
```

Comment: is `obj.Value` is `0` then this snippet would be wrong.

Comment: I love me a good oneliner, but I get `variable obj is implicity declared` why is this?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran The code is same as in the question. The condition `if (!o.Value){` will also evaluated as `false` for `0`.

Comment: @Tushar ah i missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @klskl That is a warning and can be ignored. I've updated answer to allow `0` value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var isTrue = objectArray.every(function(i) {
    return i.Value;
}
```