# How to verify a key of object exists within a Javascript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have a array like below.

```
cont arr= [ { id: 1, username: 'fred' }, { id: 2, username: 'bill' }, { id: 2, username: 'ted' } ]
```

Can I know how to verify a 'username' is exist in the array object?

Comment: or [return true if all objects in array has value in property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148546/return-true-if-all-objects-in-array-has-value-in-property) or [Checking an array if all objects inside contains a given key value(javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68857827/checking-an-array-if-all-objects-inside-contains-a-given-key-valuejavascript) if looking for specific value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check if a key exist in all elements of the array you can do this

```js
const arr= [ { id: 1, username: 'fred' }, { id: 2, username: 'bill' }, { id: 2, username: 'ted' } ]



const existsKey = (data, key) => data.every(d => d.hasOwnProperty(key))

console.log('username', existsKey(arr, 'username'))

console.log('anotherKey', existsKey(arr, 'anotherKey'))
```